# question about drawing with out java2D

Tags: java

I have another question, this is also extra credit and not homework. This time I need to create a border with out using java2d. The instructions are...
Write a method called drawRectangleBorder having six parameters which does not use the graphics package. It draws a rectangular border starting at the x and y coordinates given as the first two parameters, having a width and height given by the third and fourth parameters, the width of the border given by the fifth parameter in the color given by the sixth parameter. The parameter list is: x, y, width, height, borderWidth, color

I used a previous method I made to create a border around the outside of a picture but the best I can make it do now is a couple scattered boxes. The most recent version will not show anything

```
public void drawRectangleBorder(
        int x, int y, int width, int height, int border, Color newColor) {
    int startX = 0;
    int startY = 0;

    // top and bottom  
    for (startX = x; x < width; x++) {
        for (startY = y; y < border; y++) {
            // top pixel
            this.getPixel(startX, startY).setColor(newColor);
            // bottom pixel
            this.getPixel(startX + width, startY + height).setColor(newColor);
        } // for-y
    } // for-x

    // left and right  
    for (startX = x; x < border; x++) {
        for (startY = y; y < height; y++) {
            // left pixel
            this.getPixel(startX, startY).setColor(newColor);
            // right pixel
            this.getPixel(startX + width, StartY + height).setColor(newColor);
        } // for-y
    } // for-x

    return;
} // end drawRectangleBorder
```

Again I thank you for any input.

Comment: I think extra credit is still classified as homework ^^ (if what I posted doesn't help and nobody else flies to the rescue can you detail a bit more what your this object is)

Comment: "this" is what ever picture the method is being applied to. ie pic1.drawRectangleBorder(1,2,3,4,5,6) or pic2.drawRectangleBorder(1,2,3,4,5,6).

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the pixels in a `java.awt.BufferedImage` as shown [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/raster).

Answer (score 0):

I might be too sleepy but I think your forgetting to set the pixel back into this (whatever this is ^^)

I'm guessing this.getPixel sends your back a copy so you might want to do something like

```
Pixel p = this.getPixel( startX, startY );
p.setColor(newColor);
this.setPixel(startX, startY, p);
```

Comment: You don't need the `this` in front of method invocations. It doesn't signify anything.

Comment: @Steve Kuo: In this case, think it's being used as a placeholder for whatever `this` is in the question, perhaps an instructor-supplied wrapper for [`WritableRaster`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html).

Comment: @Steve Kuo: I only put the this because its how its written in the question ^^